# Sbt test errors with java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt

I've converted a boolean attribute of 3 case classes with following

```
import slick.ast.BaseTypedType
import slick.jdbc.JdbcType
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
import spray.json._

sealed trait Activeness {
  def unary_! : Activeness = Activeness(!this.value)
  override def toString: String = value.toString
  def value: Boolean
}

object Activeness extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  case object Active extends Activeness {
    override def value: Boolean = true
  }
  case object Inactive extends Activeness {
    override def value: Boolean = false
  }

  def apply(value: Boolean): Activeness = if (value) Active else Inactive

  val active: Activeness = Active
  val inactive: Activeness = Inactive

  implicit val activenessColumnType: JdbcType[Activeness] with BaseTypedType[Activeness] =
    MappedColumnType.base[Activeness, Boolean](_.value, Activeness.apply)

  implicit lazy val activenessFormat: RootJsonFormat[Activeness] = new RootJsonFormat[Activeness] {
    override def write(obj: Activeness): JsValue = JsBoolean(obj.value)

    override def read(json: JsValue): Activeness = {
      apply(
        json match {
          case JsNumber(n) if n == 1 => true
          case JsNumber(n) if n == 0 => false
          case JsString("1")         => true
          case JsString("0")         => false
          case JsBoolean(true)       => true
          case JsBoolean(false)      => false
          case JsString("true")      => true
          case JsString("false")     => false
          case _                     => deserializationError("Not a boolean")
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

code compiles fine but running `sbt test` I get following

```
[error] java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed:
[error]   static
[error]      while compiling: /Users/user/project/modules/api/src/test/scala/visits/validation/VisitsValidatorTest.scala
[error]         during phase: delambdafy
[error]      library version: version 2.13.4
[error]     compiler version: version 2.13.4
[error]   reconstructed args: -bootclasspath ...
[error]
[error]   last tree to typer: TypeTree(class OrderIndex)
[error]        tree position: line 357 of /Users/user/project/modules/api/src/test/scala/visits/service/VisitScheduleStudyEnvironmentServiceTest.scala
[error]             tree tpe: com.mdsol.strategicmonitoring.visits.model.OrderIndex
[error]               symbol: (final case) class OrderIndex in package model
[error]    symbol definition: final case class OrderIndex extends Product with Serializable (a ClassSymbol)
[error]       symbol package: com.mdsol.strategicmonitoring.visits.model
[error]        symbol owners: class OrderIndex
[error]            call site: method constructMonadic in package validation
[error]
[error] == Source file context for tree position ==
[error]
[error]    354   it should "create a visit schedule for shared study" in {
[error]    355     val visitSchedule = aVisitSchedule()
[error]    356     val risk =
[error]    357       random[RiskCategoryClientDivisionScheme].copy(uuid = visitSchedule.riskCategoryCdsUuid, clientDivisionSchemeUuid = visitSchedule.clientDivisionSchemeUuid)
[error]    358     val se = random[CachedPlinthStudyEnvironment]
[error]    359     val sap = random[CachedPlinthStudyAppPartnership].copy(receiverClientDivisionSchemeUuid = visitSchedule.clientDivisionSchemeUuid)
[error]    360     mockWriteSeVisitSettingsAuth(userUri, se1Uuid)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.throwAssertionError(SymbolTable.scala:170)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transformFunction(Delambdafy.scala:257)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:292)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:68)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Block.transform(Trees.scala:556)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:321)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:68)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2591)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Apply.transform(Trees.scala:786)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:321)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:68)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$DefDef.$anonfun$transform$5(Trees.scala:453)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2633)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$DefDef.transform(Trees.scala:451)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:321)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:68)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(Trees.scala:2622)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2620)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Template.transform(Trees.scala:544)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.$anonfun$transform$1(TypingTransformers.scala:53)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2633)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:306)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:68)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2595)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$ClassDef.$anonfun$transform$2(Trees.scala:361)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2633)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$ClassDef.transform(Trees.scala:360)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:57)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:321)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:68)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(Trees.scala:2622)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2620)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$PackageDef.$anonfun$transform$1(Trees.scala:342)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2633)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$PackageDef.transform(Trees.scala:342)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.$anonfun$transform$2(TypingTransformers.scala:55)
[error]     at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2633)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:43)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:38)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Delambdafy$DelambdafyTransformer.transform(Delambdafy.scala:321)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:182)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:454)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:401)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1515)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1499)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1491)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileFiles(Global.scala:1605)
[error]     at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerBridge.scala:163)
[error]     at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerBridge.scala:134)
[error]     at xsbt.CompilerBridge.run(CompilerBridge.scala:39)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:92)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$7(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:186)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:241)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:176)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$4$adapted(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:157)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.JarUtils$.withPreviousJar(JarUtils.scala:239)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:157)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:573)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:573)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5(Incremental.scala:174)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$apply$5$adapted(Incremental.scala:172)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$$anon$2.run(Incremental.scala:459)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$CycleState.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:116)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon$$anon$1.next(IncrementalCommon.scala:52)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:261)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$incrementalCompile$8(Incremental.scala:414)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.withClassfileManager(Incremental.scala:499)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.incrementalCompile(Incremental.scala:401)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.apply(Incremental.scala:166)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:573)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:491)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:332)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:420)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:137)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:2177)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$2(Defaults.scala:2134)
[error]     at sbt.internal.io.Retry$.apply(Retry.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.internal.io.Retry$.apply(Retry.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.internal.server.BspCompileTask$.compute(BspCompileTask.scala:31)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1(Defaults.scala:2130)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (api / Test / compileIncremental) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed:
[error]   static
[error]      while compiling: /Users/user/project/modules/api/src/test/scala/visits/validation/VisitsValidatorTest.scala
[error]         during phase: delambdafy
[error]      library version: version 2.13.4
[error]     compiler version: version 2.13.4
[error]   reconstructed args: -bootclasspath ...
[error]
[error]   last tree to typer: TypeTree(class OrderIndex)
[error]        tree position: line 357 of /Users/user/project/modules/api/src/test/scala/visits/service/VisitScheduleStudyEnvironmentServiceTest.scala
[error]             tree tpe: com.mdsol.strategicmonitoring.visits.model.OrderIndex
[error]               symbol: (final case) class OrderIndex in package model
[error]    symbol definition: final case class OrderIndex extends Product with Serializable (a ClassSymbol)
[error]       symbol package: com.mdsol.strategicmonitoring.visits.model
[error]        symbol owners: class OrderIndex
[error]            call site: method constructMonadic in package validation
[error]
[error] == Source file context for tree position ==
[error]
[error]    354   it should "create a visit schedule for shared study" in {
[error]    355     val visitSchedule = aVisitSchedule()
[error]    356     val risk =
[error]    357       random[RiskCategoryClientDivisionScheme].copy(uuid = visitSchedule.riskCategoryCdsUuid, clientDivisionSchemeUuid = visitSchedule.clientDivisionSchemeUuid)
[error]    358     val se = random[CachedPlinthStudyEnvironment]
[error]    359     val sap = random[CachedPlinthStudyAppPartnership].copy(receiverClientDivisionSchemeUuid = visitSchedule.clientDivisionSchemeUuid)
[error]    360     mockWriteSeVisitSettingsAuth(userUri, se1Uuid)
[error] (api-test / Test / test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 251 s (04:11), completed Jan 31, 2021 8:11:19 PM
✔ ~/project [develop|●1✚ 46]
20:11 $
```

Any ideas/pointers?

Comment: Seems like your tests are failing. Without adding [mre] it will be impossible to answer this.

Comment: It seems like your tests cannot be compiled. Run `sbt test/compile` in isolation. What is `random` doing? Seems to be a macro which chokes on the type `RiskCategoryClientDivisionScheme`. Otherwise, it's a bit little context to say more.